# Changing flash vod movie from html page

Tags: flash, wowza

I am very new to video on demand streaming.
   I was looking at a mechanism to implement video on demand streaming for my company.
   I was using wowza, and found that I could stream the video without much issues.

But the catch here is that, I have to type in both the server and the stream manually in the player - so as to build the rtmp link internally. I tried using JS to edit the fields etc, but then found that it is completely in flash, so it is not possible to type in these values inside it.

How is this usually done? I think I am missing some crucial understanding of the whole system. How can we dynamically update the data such that on clicking a link - for example - the video changes?

Thank you very much in advance,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to continue using the example provided by Wowza, the actionscript file will need to be modified to include the server/stream name you manually entered earlier.

The links below are two examples of how to use a player other than Wowza's:

http://www.osmf.org/configurator/fmp/

http://mediafront.org/osmplayer/#.UT4nmBy0J8E